# I ran into LCD problem

Tags: lcd

I am using Arduino mega 2560 and [LCD with I2C](http://www.sainsmart.com/new-sainsmart-iic-i2c-twi-1602-serial-lcd-module-display-for-arduino-uno-mega-r3.html). it is working well powered by USB but not working powered by external wall charger (9vDC). The LCD is on without any character.
Do you know the issue and do I need to adjust the brightness and how?
Thanks!

Comment: Show us a schematic and we can better help you...

Comment: @Jason:http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php?title=I2C/TWI_LCD1602_Module_%28SKU:_DFR0063%29

Comment: Have you touched the components on your arduino to see if any are hot when powered like this? Plug in the 9V adapter and have everything plugged in then see if anything is hot. Use a multimeter on the voltage source on the board to see what it sees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you have provided shows a LCD that is rated for 5V. You are powering your LCD with a 9V wall adapter. I'd expect your LCD not to operate (and possibly even damaged).

Answer (score 0):

[Provided you have regulate your 9V power supply to 5V] Your external wall charger might have more noise compared to your USB power supply. Try probing with oscilloscope to check. Adding come capacitor might help reduce the noise.